# Sending Mail in Android

Tags: android, email, alarmmanager

My application is Scheduled based app. I want to send email from default account which is configured on device.

Whenever we set any schedule, it'll notify by that time. In that time i want to send mail to receiver whose address already set in Textview. **But, these process must run in Background.**

How can i done this by that notifying time and sending mail with default account?

Anyone help me to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can i done this by that notifying time and sending mail with default account?

The time portion your problem can be handled by `AlarmManager`.

Android does not have the concept of a "default" email account, mostly because Android does not have the concept of email. Email is something provided by an application, not the operating system. Furthermore, neither the Email nor the Gmail apps that typically come on an Android device support third-party applications sending email in the background without user involvement. If you really want to send emails in the background, you will either need to implement your own SMTP/IMAP client (e.g., with JavaMail) or have your app contact some Web service that you create that sends the emails on your behalf.